# Cucumber Capybara checking for ranges of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

So I'm building a simple test whever after some calculation I want to display a number on the screen between X1 and X2.

This is how I'm currently doing it but it does not work

```
Then /^I should see value between (\d+) and (\d+)$/ do |arg1, arg2|
find_field("resultado").value.should >= arg1.to_f
find_field("resultado").value.should <= arg2.to_f
end
```

Comment: What about your code does not work? What is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: What's the result of `find_field("resultado").value`?  Can it be compared with a Float?

Comment: find_field("resultado").value is indeed a float